# opensplice dds Hello Word Example

Tags: data-distribution-service, opensplice

I am posting here after asking the question at the openslice dds forum, and not receiving any reply.I am trying to use opensplice dds on a ubuntu machine. I am not sure if it serves as a proof of proper installation, but I have pasted my `release.com`  file below. Now, I was able to run the ping pong example just fine. But when I ran the executable `sac_helloworld_pub` ( `HelloWorld` example in the C programming language), I got the following error

```
vishal@expmach:~/HDE/x86.linux2.6/examples/dcps/HelloWorld/c/standalone$    ./sac_helloworld_pub

Error in DDS_DomainParticipantFactory_create_participant: Creation failed: invalid handle
```

I did some searching, and it looks like I need to be running the `ospl start` command from the terminal. But when I do so, I get a `No command ospl found` message. Below is the `release.com`file's contents

---

```
echo "<<< OpenSplice HDE Release V6.3.130716OSS For x86.linux2.6, Date 2013-07-30 >>>"
if [ "${SPLICE_ORB:=}" = "" ]
then
   SPLICE_ORB=DDS_OpenFusion_1_6_1
   export SPLICE_ORB
fi
if [ "${SPLICE_JDK:=}" = "" ]
then
    SPLICE_JDK=jdk
    export SPLICE_JDK
fi
OSPL_HOME="/home/vishal/HDE/x86.linux2.6"
OSPL_TARGET=x86.linux2.6
PATH=$OSPL_HOME/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OSPL_HOME/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:}$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CPATH=$OSPL_HOME/include:$OSPL_HOME/include/sys:${CPATH:=}
OSPL_URI=file://$OSPL_HOME/etc/config/ospl.xml
OSPL_TMPL_PATH=$OSPL_HOME/etc/idlpp
. $OSPL_HOME/etc/java/defs.$SPLICE_JDK
export OSPL_HOME OSPL_TARGET PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH CPATH OSPL_TMPL_PATH OSPL_URI
$@
  release.com (END)
```

Comment: Did you actually source the `release.com` file in your current shell (via `. release.com`)?

Comment: Yes, I ran the command "source release.com"

Comment: You need to do `ospl start` indeed, and the command `ospl` is supposed to be in `$OSPL_HOME/bin`. You should check out to see if it is there. If it is, then you should see if that directory is actually in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the holidays-driven lack of  'reactivity' on the OpenSplice forum .. I've answered your question there though ..

Here's that same answer for completeness:

*For the 6.3 community-edition, the deployment-model changed from shared-memory (v5.x) to the so-called single-process standalone deployment mode where the middleware is simply  linked (as libraries) with the application so you don't need to start any daemons first (as was the case for the federated 'shared-memory' mode that was the default in V5). 
So its OK that you get the error when trying to call 'ospl' as thats not used anymore so isn't in the distribution.
Now to your issue, your release.com looks OK to me, but perhaps you didn't actually 'source' it in your environment i.e. calling it with a '.' in front of it:
promtp> . release.com 
you can verify that by doing an 'echo  $OSPL_HOME' in your shell and see if it actually shows the value of the env. variable as set by the release.com.
Hope that helps,

-Hans*